# Read data from a text file and convert images to PDF referred to it

Tags: bash, shell, pdf, copy, imagemagick-convert

I have a text file with this content:

```
123412-01
123413-01
123411-01
123414-01
123415-01
```

I would like to write a script (Bash/shell/command line or PHP) that will select the 6 first digits for each line and copy the files in an other directory that contains images named like that.

```
123412-123.jpg
123412-124.jpg
123412-123.jpg
123413-123.jpg
123414-123.jpg
123415-123.jpg
123416-123.jpg
```

I don't know if I'm clear in my question.

1. Read the first line and select the 3 first digits (keep it in memory)
2. Read the first line and now select the 6 first digits (keep it in memory)
3. Convert the images (in a second directory) that contain the 3 first digits and the nine 6 in folder and subfolder. For Example using the command:

   ```
    convert /blabla/Images/H(3 first digits)/(6digits)-*.jpg /test/PDF/(6digits)-01.pdf
   ```
4. Read the second line...

I have write this code to try it but it's not working.

```
    cat id.txt
    sF= cut -b 1-3 id.txt
    F=cut cut -b 1-6 id.txt

    while read -r line ; 

    do

    convert /blabla/Images/H$sF/$F.jpg /test/PDF/'$F'-01.pdf

    done
```

I think I'm doing wrong with the variable and the path but I can't find any solution to solve it.

Comment: Cool....what have tried so far?

Comment: Yes it is possible with a shell script.

Comment: Ok thank you I will go in this direction and post what I will be able to do.

Comment: I updated my question by adding my code and new informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
   first3=${line:0:3}
   first6=${line:0:6}
   echo convert "/blah/blah/images/H${first3}/${first6}-*.jpg" "/test/PDF/${first6}-01.pdf"
done < file.txt
```

which gives this:

**Sample Output**

```
convert /blah/blah/images/H123/123412-*.jpg /test/PDF/123412-01.pdf
convert /blah/blah/images/H123/123413-*.jpg /test/PDF/123413-01.pdf
convert /blah/blah/images/H123/123411-*.jpg /test/PDF/123411-01.pdf
convert /blah/blah/images/H123/123414-*.jpg /test/PDF/123414-01.pdf
convert /blah/blah/images/H123/123415-*.jpg /test/PDF/123415-01.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you I tried it and it work just fine. Do you what should I add to execute every "convert" ?

Comment: Make a copy of your files first in case it doesn't do what you want, then edit the script and remove the word `echo` on the second to last line. At the moment it only echoes onto the screen what it *would* do instead of actually doing anything, so if you remove the `echo`, it will actually do it.

Answer (score 1):

bash:

```
cat file.txt|cut -b 1-6|while read N; do cp "FIRSTDIR/image_$N.jpg" SECONDDIR; done
```